# Hibernate retrieving data throws nullpointerexception

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am making several classes and trying to retrieve data but it throws Exception.
I am unable to find out.
Here is my code....

This is LogIn class which creates table LogIn in database.

```
package entity_classes;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class LogIn{

@EmbeddedId
private PrimaryKeyLogIn primarykeylogin=new PrimaryKeyLogIn();

public PrimaryKeyLogIn getPrimarykeylogin() {
    return primarykeylogin;
}

public void setPrimarykeylogin(PrimaryKeyLogIn primarykeylogin) {
    this.primarykeylogin = primarykeylogin;
}



}
```

This is PrimaryKeyLogIn class which is embedded to create composite primary key in LogIn table.

```
package entity_classes;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class PrimaryKeyLogIn implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String Username,Password,Type;

public PrimaryKeyLogIn(){}

public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    Username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}

public String getType() {
    return Type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    Type = type;
}


}
```

This is main class CheckLogIn which i thought that throws Exception.

```
package entity_classes;

public class CheckLogIn {

public boolean getuser()
{
    LogIn l=new LogIn();
    LogIn lg=new LogIn();
    PrimaryKeyLogIn pkg=new PrimaryKeyLogIn();
    PrimaryKeyLogIn pklg=new PrimaryKeyLogIn();
    pklg.setUsername("KAMANI");
    pklg.setPassword("KAMANI");
    pklg.setType("Admin");
    lg.setPrimarykeylogin(pklg);

    SessionCreator.session=SessionCreator.sessionfactory.openSession();
    SessionCreator.session.beginTransaction();
    l=(LogIn) SessionCreator.session.get(LogIn.class,pkg);
    pkg=l.getPrimarykeylogin();
    System.out.println(pkg.getUsername());
    SessionCreator.session.getTransaction().commit();
    SessionCreator.session.close();
    /*if(pkg.getUsername().equals(pklg.getUsername())&&pkg.getPassword().equals(pklg.getPassword())&&pkg.getType().equals(pklg.getType()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;*/
    return true;

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    CheckLogIn cli=new CheckLogIn();
    cli.getuser();
}

}
```

Now when i am running above CheckLogIn code it shows the following Exception which is same as the previous but quietly simplified. Watch out i here used the main method in CheckLogIn so i am running that class only passing no arguments.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hibernate: select login0_.Password as Password0_0_, login0_.Type as Type0_0_, login0_.Username as Username0_0_ from LogIn login0_ where login0_.Password=? and login0_.Type=? and login0_.Username=?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at entity_classes.CheckLogIn.getuser(CheckLogIn.java:19)
at entity_classes.CheckLogIn.main(CheckLogIn.java:34)
```

Comment: Can you post detailed `Log`??

Comment: Seems that `primarykeylogin` attribute of the Login object is aquiring `null` value. Check it into the DB.

Comment: Can you show us the line "CheckLogIn.java:14"

Comment: @XtremeBiker there is already data. Let me simplify the above code. See the Edit.

Comment: Where are your `equals` and `hashcode` methods of your primary key object?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!
After Debugging for long time i found small mistake.

Here i must have to pass pklg object.

I am writing the correct code that is in CheckLogIn class.

```
l=(LogIn) SessionCreator.session.get(LogIn.class,pklg);
```

While i passed the pkg object so it throws null pointer exception.